# Como eu pego o id do depois do select?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

o usuario seleciona um user pelo nome, eu preciso descobrir qual o id escolhido. Obrigado pessoal, sou novo em Laravel!

Como eu pego o valor de users->id?

```
{!! Form::select(
    'id_users',
    $users->pluck('name'),
    $users->pluck('id'),
    [],
    ['class' => 'form-control']
) !!}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pelas correções Guilherme Cosamilam!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Uau! Depois de dois dias descobri o erro... apenas no meu form original tinha uma virgula sobrando. O Código está correto e o $users->pluck('id') é o código que eu preciso na função! Obrigado a todos aqueles que tentaram me ajudar...